# .NET Core Self Accessing QueryFilters

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I'm looking for a work around for an [EntityFramework Core Bug](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20896). I'm trying to write a query which filters on itself.

> **Disclaimer:**  I'm doing something a bit more complex than filtering by an explicit `userId`, I am just using this with a hard-coded value for simplicity, as the exact implementation isn't relevant to my question.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) =>
    modelBuilder.Entity<ConversationSubscription>()
        .HasQueryFilter(x => x.Conversation.ConversationSubscriptions
            .Select(c => c.UserId).Contains(315)
        );
```

Since the Query Filter is attempting to access the entity in which it's filtering, it ends up in and endless loop. Since we're working with the `ModelBuilder` and not the `DbSet`, there is no way to mark it as `IgnoreQueryFilters`.

Given this, I tried to use the current context to filter itself:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ConversationSubscription>().HasQueryFilter(x => 
    this.Set<ConversationSubscription().AsNoTracking().IgnoreQueryFilters()
        .Where(cs => cs.ConversationId == x.ConversationId)
            .Select(c => c.UserId)
            .Contains(315)
);
```

However, this throws an `InvalidOperationException`, most likely because we're attempting to use the context before `OnModelCreating` has finished.

I feel like there is a way I can hack around this if I can somehow select the `ConversationSubsriptions` into an Anonymous Type, such that they're unfiltered.

**Edit:** I tried to hack around this using an anonymous type, but no luck.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ConversationSubscription>().HasQueryFilter(c =>
    x => x.Conversation.Messages.Select(m => new {
        Value = m.Conversation.ConversationSubscriptions.Distinct()
            .Select(cs => cs.UserId).Contains(c.Variable(this._userId)) 
    }).FirstOrDefault().Value
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query filters initially didn't support accessing navigation properties or db sets. Looks like EF Core 3.0 removed these limitations (probably because of the new [Single SQL statement per LINQ query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#single-sql-statement-per-linq-query) mode), with the following restrictions/bugs:

1. `AsNoTracking()` and `AsTracking()` - not supported, which makes sense, since the query filter is always translated to SQL.
2. `Include` / `ThenInclude` - allowed, but ignored by the same reason.
3. `IgnoreQueryFilters` - not supported. This could be considered as bug since it could have been be used to resolve the next cases.
4. Cross referencing filters (e.g. entity `A` filter uses entity `B` and entity `B` filter uses entity `A`) via either navigation properties or db sets - cause `StackOverflowException` because filters are trying to use each other. This is a bug.
5. Self referencing filter via navigation properties - same bug as #4, should be like #6.
6. Self referencing filter via db sets - supported(!), always ignored in filter subquery.

With all that being said, luckily your case is supported by #6, i.e. your second attempt with just unsupported `AsNoTracking()` and `IgnoreQueryFilters()` removed:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ConversationSubscription>().HasQueryFilter(x => 
    this.Set<ConversationSubscription()
        .Where(cs => cs.ConversationId == x.ConversationId)
              .Select(c => c.UserId)
              .Contains(315));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here Johnny, so if I'm way off the mark, my apologies.

But I feel like you're doing this:

- `From conversation subscriptions, join conversations, then join conversation subscriptions where user id = 315`

While you could/should be doing this:

- `From conversation subscriptions where user id = 315, join conversations.`

I fail to see what the round trip in your query is necessary for, since it looks like you are querying from ConversationSubscription. In such a query, a simple include will return only conversations and conversationsubscriptions that a user has access to. Is that not what you want to return?

`var result = context.ConversationSubscriptions.Include(c => c.Conversation).ToList();`

```cs
private int _userId = 315;

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ConversationSubscription>()
        .HasQueryFilter(x => x.UserId.Contains(_userId));
}
```

Comment: Dennis a user should have access to other users subscription who are in the same conversation.  Imagine you want to create a conversation with another user, you'll need to be able to create a subscription for them.